# Sending email using EWS from Office365 with nonexistent from address

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

I have making a mail ingestion task for an internal helpdesk application.
The intention is to use a Office365 Exchange online instance with a single mailbox configured to be a catch all.

The idea is to send email with Exchange Web Services (EWS) using nonexistent from addresses, i.e. ticket-1234@mydomainname.com. This way the recipient can send/reply to a specific/known mailbox.

If at all possible I don't want to have to create virtual mailbox or aliases for every ticket, as we have literally 10s of thousands of tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that - Exchange will not let you spoof an email address. You can only send as one of the proxy addressees owned by the mailbox used to send the message or the user whose credentials are used to connect to the outgoing Exchange SMTP server.

Comment: You are totally correct. I found another way of doing it

Comment: @Rhett Leech - using Exchange?